# What's the means about the matrix that TfidVectorizer.transform(['word1 word2 word3']) returns , and how does it calculate it

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

Inorder to get a tfidf maxtrix,i trained 50000 documents by sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer,

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vec = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words_file_list,smooth_idf=True)
crops_vect = vec.fit_transform(crops).toarray()
```

I know that the crops_vect row is each documents , and the column is the word extracted from the whole corpus,
such as crops_vect[document_id1]  represents a vector constituted by tdidf trained by  the corpus .
My question is, what does vec.transform(['america strong'].toarray() mean:

```
np.where(vec.transform(['america strong']).toarray())
>>>(array([0, 0]), array([112609, 195997]))

[i for i in vec.transform(['america strong']).toarray()[0] if i != 0]
>>>[0.675671442580281, 0.7372028904456914]

[i for i in vec.transform(['strong']).toarray()[0] if i != 0]
>>>[1]
```

I looked at the vector of the word 'strong' in the corpus

```
np.array([i for i in crops_vect.T[195997].toarray()[0] ])
>>>array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])
np.where(np.array([i for i in crops_vect.T[195997].toarray()[0] ]))
>>>array([   20,   239,   250,   272,   303,   786,   797,   836,   924,
         1202,  1218,  1613,  1645,  1651,  1662,  1670,  1673,  1688,
         1691,  1697,  1721,  1728,  1766,  1780,  1849,  1935,  1975,
         1988,  1999,  2017,  2018,  2199,  2344,  2354,  2721,  2752,
         2775,  2785,  2788,  2809,  2818,  2826,  2830,  2841,  2844,
         .....]
```

what's my question is :
1)i had know vec.transform(['strong']).toarray() != crops_vect.T[195997].toarray(),
and  what's means vec.transform(['strong']).toarray()

2)what's represent of  vec.transform(['word1','word2']),
Is it equivalent to adding a new document ['word1','word2'] to the previously trained tfidf matrix and then to calculate a new tdidf matrix of the new document?

3)vec.transform(['word1','word2']) ,How does it calculate it internally

thanks

Comment: i think i had solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words_file_list,smooth_idf=True)
so idf computational formula is:

```
idf(t) = log [ n / df(t) ] + 1
```

vec.transform(['word1','word2']) is two onehot vector  vertical linkage;
vec.transform(['word1  word2']) is a document consisted of two words "word1 word2",calculate the word1's df and word1's idf in the trained documents crops
calc df and idf ,
finally normalize
v1/sqrt(v1**2 + v2**2),v2/sqrt(v1**2 + v2**2)